# Show that if matrix $X$ satisfies the relation $X \cdot Y = Y \cdot X$ it has a specific form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

Show that: If $X \in \mathbb{R}^{2x2}$ is a matrix which satisfies the relation $X \cdot Y = Y \cdot X$ for all $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{2x2}$, then $X$ has the form $X = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0\\ 
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

I don't know how to solve this task? Maybe we are allowed to set specific matrix for $Y$? But I'm not sure because it's saying "for all" so we must stay general?

Else I would say we can satisfy this relation when we set $Y = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ I think.

But that's not enough to prove it right? : /

Comment: Show that if $X$ commutes with a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ then it commutes with all of the space. Afterward, find your favorite basis and check what $X$ need to satisfy in order to commute with each of its elements.

Comment: $XY=YX$ is supposed to hold for _all possible_ $Y$ simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding the comment of Ofir:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0\\ 
c & 0
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
implies $b = c = 0$.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a\\ 
0 & c
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
c & d\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
implies $a = d$.

Answer (score 2):

Be $X=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$. Now choose $Y=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then you have
$$XY = \begin{pmatrix}b&a\\d&c\end{pmatrix} \stackrel!= YX=\begin{pmatrix}c&d\\a&b\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore we get $a=d$ and $b=c$, that is,
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$$
Now choose $Y=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then you have
$$XY = \begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&0\end{pmatrix} \stackrel!= YX = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Clearly this is only possible if $b=0$. Therefore we now have
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$$
It is easy to check that this matrix indeed commutes with all other matrices, therefore we've found the general form.

Answer (score -1):

$A,B,C,D$ can be any number you like.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 \lambda &0 \\ 
 0& \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 A&B \\ 
 C&D 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 A\lambda &B\lambda  \\ 
 C\lambda & D\lambda 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 A&B \\ 
 C&D 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 \lambda &0 \\ 
 0& \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}$$
hence for all $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{2x2}$, it satisfies the relation $X \cdot Y = Y \cdot X$.

Comment: This answer proves a statement which is not equivalent to the one requested.

Answer (score -2):

Since $X = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0\\ 
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}$ and $XY = YX$ then define $Y=\begin{pmatrix}
\ y_1 & y_2\\ 
y_3 & y_4
\end{pmatrix}$

Then we have $$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0\\ 
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\ y_1 & y_2\\ 
y_3 & y_4
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\ y_1 & y_2\\ 
y_3 & y_4
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0\\ 
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}$$

This gives us the following system of linear equations:

$$\begin{cases}\lambda y_1 = \lambda y_1 \\ \lambda y_2 = \lambda y_2 \\ \lambda y_3 = \lambda y_3 \\ \lambda y_4 = \lambda y_4\end{cases}$$

This system of linear equations tells you that $X$ and $Y$ commute.

Comment: This answer proves a statement which is not equivalent to the one requested.